# A* algorithm works silly with heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding

I'm trying to use A* and visualised it, but when i add a heap optimization it start looking  in incredeble ways sometimes normal(better then next to be sure), somtimes he looks on few columns.
[image: Example with heap]

Normal working without heap

[image: Example without heap]

Code:

Pathfinding.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "Heap.h"


class Pathfinding
{
public:
    std::vector<Node*> openSet;
    std::vector<Node*> closedSet;
    std::vector<Node*> path;
    std::vector<std::vector<Node*>> grid;
    Node* startNode;
    Node* targetNode;
    bool intialized = false;
    int cols;
    int rows;
    bool find = false;
    Pathfinding(int _cols, int _rows, std::vector<std::vector<Node*>> _grid);
    ~Pathfinding();

    void FindPath(Node* start, Node* target);
    void SetStartAndGoal(Node* start, Node* goal);
    int GetDistance(Node* nodeA, Node* nodeB);
};
```

Pathfinding.cpp

```
#include "Pathfinding.h"



Pathfinding::Pathfinding(int _cols, int _rows, std::vector<std::vector<Node*>> _grid)
{
cols = _cols;
rows = _rows;
grid = _grid;
}


Pathfinding::~Pathfinding()
{
delete startNode;
delete targetNode;
openSet.clear();
closedSet.clear();
path.clear();
}

void Pathfinding::FindPath(Node* start, Node* target)
{
if (!intialized)
{

    openSet.clear();
    closedSet.clear();
    path.clear();

    std::make_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end());

    SetStartAndGoal(start, target);

    intialized = true;
}
if (intialized)
{
    if (!find)
    {
        if (openSet.size() > 0)  
        {
            Node* current = openSet.front();

            std::pop_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end());
            openSet.pop_back();

            if (current == targetNode)
            {
                Node* temp = current;
                path.push_back(temp);
                while (temp->parent)
                {
                    path.push_back(temp->parent);
                    temp = temp->parent;
                }
                std::cout << "DONE!";
                find = true;
            }

            closedSet.push_back(current);

            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                        continue;

                    int checkX = current->x + i;
                    int checkY = current->y + j;

                    if (checkX >= 0 && checkX < cols && checkY >= 0 && checkY < rows)
                    {
                        Node* neighbor = grid[checkX][checkY];
                        bool inClosed = false;
                        for (int k = 0; k < closedSet.size(); k++)
                        {
                            if (neighbor == closedSet[k])
                            {
                                inClosed = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!inClosed && neighbor->walkable)
                        {
                            int tempG = current->g + GetDistance(current, neighbor);

                            bool inOpen = false;
                            for (int k = 0; k < openSet.size(); k++)
                            {
                                if (neighbor == openSet[k])
                                {
                                    inOpen = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (inOpen)
                            {
                                if (tempG < neighbor->g)
                                {
                                    neighbor->g = tempG;
                                    neighbor->parent = current;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                neighbor->g = tempG;
                                openSet.push_back(neighbor);
                                std::push_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end());
                                neighbor->parent = current;
                            }
                            neighbor->h = GetDistance(neighbor, targetNode);
                            neighbor->f = neighbor->g + neighbor->h;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "NO SOLUTION";
            find = true;
        }
    }
}
}

void Pathfinding::SetStartAndGoal(Node* start, Node* goal)
{
startNode = new Node(start->x, start->y);
targetNode = new Node(goal->x, goal->y);

startNode = start;
targetNode = goal;

startNode->g = 0;
startNode->h = GetDistance(startNode, targetNode);
startNode->parent = 0;

openSet.push_back(startNode);
std::push_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end());
}

int Pathfinding::GetDistance(Node* nodeA, Node* nodeB)
{
int dstX = fabs(nodeA->x - nodeB->x);
int dstY = fabs(nodeA->y - nodeB->y);

if (dstX > dstY)
    return 14 * dstY + 10 * (dstX - dstY);
return 14 * dstX + 10 * (dstY - dstX);
}

bool cmp(const Node &a, const Node &b)
{
if (a.f == b.f)
    if (a.h > b.h)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
else if (a.f > b.f)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Node.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Node
{
public:
int x, y;
float f = 0;
float g = 0;
float h = 0;
bool walkable = true;
Node* parent = NULL;
sf::Color col = sf::Color::White;
Node(int i, int j);
~Node();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node(int i, int j)
{
x = i;
y = j;
}


Node::~Node()
{}
```

main

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Node.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>  
#include "Pathfinding.h"



int cols = 50;
int rows = 50;
int width = 800;
int height = 800;
int w, h;

std::vector<std::vector<Node*>> grid;
std::vector<Node*> tempGrid;

std::vector<Node*> openSet;
std::vector<Node*> closedSet;
std::vector<Node*> path;
Node* start;
Node* end;

int main()
{
//srand(time(NULL));

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "A*");

w = width / cols;
h = height / rows;

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        Node* node = new Node(i, j);
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        if (r < 0.3 && !(i == 0 && j == 0 || i == cols - 1 && j == rows - 1))
            node->walkable = false;
        tempGrid.push_back(node);
    }
    grid.push_back(tempGrid);
    tempGrid.clear();
}

Pathfinding pathfind(cols, rows, grid);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //algorithm

    pathfind.FindPath(grid[0][0], grid[cols - 1][rows - 1]);
    openSet = pathfind.openSet;
    closedSet = pathfind.closedSet;
    path = pathfind.path;

    //draw

    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    for (int i = 0; i < closedSet.size(); i++)
    {
        closedSet[i]->col = sf::Color::Red;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < openSet.size(); i++)
    {
        openSet[i]->col = sf::Color::Green;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
    {
        path[i]->col = sf::Color::Blue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(w, h));
            rectangle.setPosition(i*w, j*h);
            if (!grid[i][j]->walkable)
                rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
            else
                rectangle.setFillColor(grid[i][j]->col);
            rectangle.setOutlineThickness(-1);
            rectangle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(rectangle);
        }
    }

    window.display();
}


for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
{
    grid[i].clear();
}
grid.clear();


return 0;
```

}

What I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hint: You can take a screenshot of just the active window with Alt+Print.

Comment: @Philipp I learn something new from you just about every day. All though it can be applicable to games, I was thinking this post may be better over on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (tempG < neighbor->g)
{
    neighbor->g = tempG;
    neighbor->parent = current;
}
```

After this the heap needs to be updated so the neighbor properly bubbles up to preserve the heap property.

It would be much easier if there was a `std::change_element_heap(begin, end, it);` which assumes that except for the element at `it`, the heap invariant holds and then fixes the heap. It's possible to implement that yourself. It still requires that you find where the Node is in the heap before you can update it.

Comment: find that i dont use cmp function to compare in heap also i rearrange this fragment to `if (inOpen)
        {
         if (tempG < neighbor->g)
         {
          neighbor->g = tempG;
          neighbor->h = GetDistance(neighbor, targetNode);
          neighbor->f = neighbor->g + neighbor->h;
          neighbor->parent = current;
          std::sort_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(), cmp);
         }      }`  but now debug says that this is invalid heap

Comment: @ibvfteh s/sort_heap/make_heap/ sort heap doesn't do what you want, it instead does repeated pop_heap until the heap is empty and leaves the range sorted.

Comment: actually i tried to use make_heap and it works nicely but if you say that it don't do what i want then maybe add something like `openSet.erase(std::remove(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(), neghibor), openSet.end()); std::pop_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(), cmp); `  change parameters  `openSet.push_back(neighbor); std::push_heap(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(), cmp); ` ? but i not sure that after openSet would be a valid heap

Comment: make_heap will fix the heap but it's less efficient than if you could specify which elements were violating the heap invariant.

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: @ibvfteh you can't. Or you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: ok man I asked a teacher and she said that the make_heap is most optimal way so thanks a lot

Comment: @ratchetfreak is right, make_heap will need to scan the whole heap to find the items that need to bubble. A custom implementation can do this more efficiently, by visiting only the chain of items "above" the modified item (logarithmic rather than linear complexity). A heap doesn't take long to write and is actually very instructive, so if you have the time I'd recommend trying a custom implementation with the book-keeping required to do these updates even faster than your current version.